# C# WPF : how can i access page controls from another page to get textbox.text

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello i just started learning WPF and i'm confused.
i have 2 pages i want to get `TextBox.text` value form page2 how?
in page1.xaml.cs:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Page2 p = new Page2();
        MessageBox.Show(p.textbox1.Text);
    }
```

the code i provided when i click the button messagebox show up empty and
textbox1 contains text.

please explain how can i access p.textbox1.Text value in correct way.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the way you should go about this.  Take some time and learn the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) architectural pattern.

Comment: please mention a good source to learn MVVM beginners friendly.

Comment: In which page is `Button_Click` defined? And how this page relate to `Page2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understund well, you want to pass a value from a class to other class.
So you should create a method that returs your value like this :

**In page 1**

```
   Page2 p = new Page2();
   p.getTextBox();
```

**In page 2**

```
    public string getTextBox(){
      return  TextBox.text ;
     }
```

Also, you can work with static variables or a file xml to save your string.
I hope taht it helped you.